# Spring interceptor intercepting late

Tags: spring, filter, interceptor

Spring boot 2.1.7 running a test server -- need to check my cache for a hit using the url as key, and then act based on a cache hit or not.

I send a request from my browser for https://localhost:8443/test/param=value --- my filter picks it up, and using code from another answer on SO, the filter constructs the url -- the filter code sees the url is https://localhost:8443/test?param=value
Great!
Then my interceptor gets hit (thanks to Theo on SO), but it thinks the url is https://localhost:8443/favicon.ico -- what's up with that?  Not much of an interceptor if I didn't get to intercept the original /test url.

To get around that, in the filter, I stored the "real" url in the ServletContext, and that variable is read out correctly in the interceptor.  Seems like an awful hack, and silly that I have to do it.  For now I've hard-coded the decision to redirect to url /test2, but back in Chrome, I see the output from test1, not test2.

The network tab in Chrome seems to suggest: [image: test1 output and redirection from favicon]

that I was redirected to test2, but only after a request for favicon got inserted (for whatever mysterious reason) and yet as the image shows, the output is clearly test1, not test2.

Something I don't understand is that devtools also shows a response from test2:

[image: test2 output in devtools]

@WebFilter( urlPatterns = "/test", description = "a filter for test servlet", initParams = {
        @WebInitParam( name = "msg", value = "==> " ) }, filterName = "test filter" )
public class TestFilter implements Filter
{

```
private FilterConfig filterConfig;


@Override
public void doFilter( ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain )
        throws IOException, ServletException
{
    String url = getCurrentUrlFromRequest( servletRequest );
    // in the debugger, url is correctly shown as
    //  https://localhost:8443/test/param=value
    if ( null != url )
    {
        ServletContext s = servletRequest.getServletContext();
        s.setAttribute( "realUrl", url );
    }
    servletResponse.getOutputStream().print( filterConfig.getInitParameter( "msg" ) );
    filterChain.doFilter( servletRequest, servletResponse );

public String getCurrentUrlFromRequest( ServletRequest request )
{
    if ( !( request instanceof HttpServletRequest ) ) return null;

    return getCurrentUrlFromRequest( (HttpServletRequest) request );
}

public String getCurrentUrlFromRequest( HttpServletRequest request )
{
    StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();
    String queryString = request.getQueryString();

    if ( queryString == null ) return requestURL.toString();

    return requestURL.append( '?' ).append( queryString ).toString();
}

@Override
public void destroy()
{
}

@Override
public void init( FilterConfig filterConfig ) throws ServletException
{
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
}
```

}

//then the interceptor:

@Component
public class CheckForCacheInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor
{

```
@Bean
public MappedInterceptor myInterceptor()
{
    CheckForCacheInterceptor ci = new CheckForCacheInterceptor();
    ci.setRedirectMapping( "/test2" );
    return new MappedInterceptor( null, ci  );
}

private String redirectMapping;

@Override
public boolean preHandle( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler )
{
    String url = (String) request.getServletContext().getAttribute( "realUrl" );
    // "realUrl" has https://localhost:8443/test/param=value, but I'd like 
    // to get rid of hack.  Problem is that right here, running the same 
    // exact code (copy/paste of filter's
    // getCurrentUrlFromRequest( HttpServletRequest request ) method )
    //which gets the correct url in the filter yields 
    // https://localhost:8443/favicon.ico  -- where did that come from?

    // TODO check cache using requestUrl as key

    boolean foundInCache = false;
    if ( foundInCache ) 
    {
        // TODO: somehow write cache value to response
        // then send response
        return false;
    } else 
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO:  make direct request, 
            // get response body, then 
            response.sendRedirect( redirectMapping );
            return false;
        } catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

So before my questions pile up to the ceiling, I'll ask for help -- how is this favicon request sneaking in before my interceptor even has a crack at the original url, why can't I get the original url in my interceptor, and given that the Chrome devtools shows I am getting through to test2, how is the output coming from the test1 servlet instead of the test2 servlet?

FWIW, I'm getting the exact same behavior in Postman.  Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: You're just looking at two separate requests from the browser: one to load the page (/test/param=value) and the other to load the favicon (/favicon.ico).

Answer (score 0):

I read another answer on SO (sorry I don't have the link) which has fixed the issue of not intercepting the initial get request to /test -- it said that interceptors only intercept requests going to Controllers, so I needed to have a Controller which was mapped to /test.  After writing a quickie Controller, the interceptor is now intercepting as one might expect.